# How to import JavaScript from an external file

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to import some functions from a HS file into my HTML file.

This is the JavaScript file, called index.js

```
 import { Network } from "./node_modules/alchemy-sdk/dist/cjs/index.js";
 import { Alchemy }  from "./node_modules/alchemy-sdk/dist/cjs/index.js";

 // Optional Config object, but defaults to demo api-key and eth-mainnet.
 const settings = {
   apiKey: "IDF0Mtzrz8aOWisaF4Ele7m7tfCX_Gaj",
   network: Network.MATIC_MAINNET,
};

 const alchemy = new Alchemy(settings);

 async function f1(){
 const nfts = await 
 alchemy.nft.getNftsForOwner("0xF32FA29Ef7041Ff159c3d5b8eA726cA391b7108f").then(console.log);
 }

  function f2(){
  console.log(1);
  }

   export {f1, f2};
```

I've created 2 functions, the second one is just for test purposes and exported em both as seen on the last row of code

In the HTML file, in the head section, i've added the following code

```
  <script type ="module">
    import * as scripts from "./index.js"
  </script>
```

But whenever I try to call scripts.f1 or f2 from my HTML file I get told that scripts are not defined.

I've also tried importing the functions only by doing Import {f1, f2} from "./index.js" but the result in that case is that either f1 or f2 is not defined...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is a scoping issue. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#scoped_modules_for_version_management) imported modules are only available to the script that imports them. That means, in your case, it's your `<script>` tag. If you were to do

```
<script type ="module">
    import * as scripts from "./index.js"
    console.log(scripts)
</script>
```

You would probably output an object containing `f1` and `f2`.

To access the functions elsewhere, you could attach whatever you imported to the `window` object, after doing so.

[Here](https://github.com/KerimG/JS-modules-in-HTML-example) is an example that works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type ="module">
    import {f1, f2} from "./index.js"
</script>
```